# Debug Form.py files with Pydev and Qgis debug plugin

Tags: pyqgis, pydev

Following Python Qgis cookbook, qgis doc and other usefull docs, I succesfully installed and configure the debugger for pluggin as "hello world".
But, in the case of specific form, based on python script and Qt .ui files, I cannot figure out how to debug with the Pydev debug server.

I did :

- run the debug server and the qgis plugin
- set the python file path on Qgis
- set the python file path on Pydev project,
- set a breakpoint on def formOpen(): function
- open the form under Qgis

The debugger never stop on the breakpoint.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debug a **QGIS plugins** using your configuration and **IDE** the steps for **eclipse** projec are:

- install [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)
- Install [PyDev plugin for eclipse](http://www.pydev.org/download.html)
- Create a  in [PyDev project](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf.html) your IDE
- Set the PyDev path in the  **__init__.py** (in my case)

> ```
> try:
>     sys.path.append("D:/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.9.2.201708151115/pysrc")
> except:
>     pass
> ```

- In your other class need import pydev:

> ```
> try:
>     import sys
>     from pydevd import *
> except:
>     None
> ```

- For put a break point you need put the first time `settrace()` for stop the code in this class

And for example in a Load-QSS Plugin I'm stopping the code when open a main form:

[image]

Note that I have put a `settrace ()` before calling this method, this way if you will recognize the next breakpoint

You can show some functional QGIS plugins using this configuration in my [Github](https://github.com/All4Gis/Load-QSS) account

Comment: thanks for your reply but did you read the question, it's about python Form ?

Comment: the steps are the same, regardless of whether it's a form, dialog, etc.

Comment: make sure that you put a `settrace()` before calling your function and that PyDev is imported...

Comment: whaoou ! you give me the answer. I define a new function called initDebugForm in which I use settrace() method, then call my formOpen function. Under Qgis layer properties define the function name to initDebugForm, and when I open the form, the debugger stop on my breackpoint. thank you so much !